# Saving Core Data entity only if it has a relationship

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two Core Data entities in my app.

The first one is called `Alarm`. The second one is called `Mission`. An `Alarm` can have multiple `Mission` entities. A `Mission` without an associated `Alarm` is useless and should be deleted/not saved.

I created these entities with a "To Many" relationship from `Alarm` to `Mission`. This relationship has **Cascade** delete rule.

I also created a relationship from `Mission` to `Alarm` as `To One`. The relationship has **Nullify** delete rule.

In my app I have to create a `Mission` before the `Alarm` to be able to set `Alarm`'s `missions` property like below:

```
let mission = Mission(context: moc)
...
```

And then later in the flow, if user taps "Save". I create the `Alarm` like below:

```
let alarm = Alarm(context: moc)
alarm.id = UUID()
alarm.missions = NSOrderedSet(array: missions)
...
```

The problem is that if the user does not tap to "Save" the alarm, the `Mission` is created and stays in the data store. (Because I save the context, every time the app is closed, and it's a must)

How can I ensure `Mission`s without an `Alarm` is not saved?

Thanks

Comment: There is no magic. You will need to code the logic yourself. You could use an optional to hold your `Mission` and only create the `Mission` when an `Alarm` is created and the property is `nil` or you could check the state of the relationship when exiting the screen and delete it if it is empty.

Comment: Also, note that using an `NSOrderedSet` when you create the `Alarm` will not preserve the order of `missions` when the object is persisted.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulw11, "You will need to code the logic yourself." It turns out this is exactly what I wanted. Created a temporary class to hold the missions and inserted them to `moc` only when Alarm is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Please have a look as per understanding, might be i m wrong, let's
  try:

  1. Create Missions Only Through Alarms: Instead of creating Mission entities independently, only allow the creation of Mission entities
     through the context of an Alarm. This ensures that every Mission is
     associated with an Alarm.
  2. Delete Orphaned Missions: Whenever you save or persist an Alarm, check its associated missions. If an Alarm has no missions, you can
     automatically delete those orphaned Mission entities right before
     saving the context.

Note : First Create Alarm with associated Missions.

```
func createAlarm() {
        let alarm = Alarm(context: moc)
        alarm.id = UUID()
        alarm.missions = NSOrderedSet(array: missions)
        
        // When user taps for "Save Action
        if alarm.missions.count > 0 {
            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                // Handle save error
            }
        } else {
            // Delete the Alarm's missions and then delete the Alarm itself
            if let missions = alarm.missions.array as? [Mission] {
                for mission in missions {
                    moc.delete(mission)
                }
            }
            moc.delete(alarm)
            
            do {
                try moc.save()
            } catch {
                // Handle save error
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer really helped me to figure out the whole flow.  Created a temporary class to hold the missions and inserted them to `moc` only when Alarm is created.